# Build failed while deploying express.js app on render.com

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, render.com

I am trying to deploy an express.js application using the web service on the render.com platform, but encountering an error in the log - 'Exited with status 2 while building your code.'

I'd like to highlight that when I execute `npm run build && npm run start` from VS Code, i.e., in a local environment, the code successfully transpiles from TypeScript to JavaScript, generates the 'dist' folder, and starts the server without any issues, connecting seamlessly to the MongoDB database.

local environment:

```
> RESTful-API-Node.js-Express.js-MongoDB@1.0.0 build
> tsc

PS C:\Users\mile_\projects\RESTful-API-Node.js-Express.js-MongoDB-Passport.js> npm run start

> RESTful-API-Node.js-Express.js-MongoDB@1.0.0 start
> node dist/index.js

Connected to MongoDB
Server is running on port 8000.
```

render.com - https://pastebin.com/SsvHenCQ

github repository - https://github.com/mile-mijatovic/RESTful-API-Node.js-Express.js-MongoDB-Passport.js

Please check if the issue stems from `src/types/express.d.ts` where I extended express and express-session." Thank you for pointing that out!